# gotfocus and KeyEventArgs

Tags: wpf

```
        private void TextBox27_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Stil53.Begin();
            TextBox27.Select(TextBox27.Text.Length, 0);
            Takvim_Kapat();
            KeyEventHandler mhth = new KeyEventHandler(TextBox27_PreviewKeyUp); <=////this
        }

        private void TextBox27_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Listelemeler.Para_Birimi_Noktalama(TextBox27, e);
        }
```

In the gotfocus incident I'm trying to trigger the KeyEventArgs event. How can I achieve this? Can you give me an idea? thank you in advance

In the gotfocus incident I'm trying to trigger the KeyEventArgs event. How can I achieve this? Can you give me an idea? thank you in advance

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to do..? what is the reason you want to trigger the KeyEventHandler?

Comment: There is a currency mask in the textbox and I need to specify a text length in the textbox and this event TextBox27_PreviewKeyUp does it.

Comment: why dont use the textchanged event and block the input following the value of the current textlength

Comment: Because when the user presses a key on the keyboard, I need to check the status before and after the comma. I just need to find a way to fire the TextBox27_PreviewKeyU event in gotfocus. Can you help me? These are all the questions you asked and more, believe me, I tried, my friend.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: no problem, but i dont understant what is your problem, you want to test the status before and after  the comma so what is this?

Comment: I think in Europe they use a dot instead of a comma, 12.02 is the currency format for you, this is 12,02 for us.

Comment: do you want to switch dot by comma ? when the user presses a key?

Comment: Being able to enter 2 characters after the comma. I already do this in my code. When the user opens the window, the length of the textbox is 9 characters. When the gotfocus event occurs, if there is a comma in the value in the textbox and 2 characters are already written after the comma, the user should not enter a value, but since it is less than 9 characters in mine, characters can be entered. I am trying to prevent this.

Comment: ok i understant its not so complex you have a maxlength of 9 but you could have a comma with 2 char after, but the comma is always present?

Comment: and when a comma is present with 2 char, you would prevent the user to enters again new char?  all chars are numbers?

Comment: Yes, it is always a number and there is a comma. There is not always a comma. Integer values ​​can also be int or decimal, depending on the amount. Thank you very much for your answer but it didn't work

Comment: you say my answer is not working, could you precise?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, but it didn't work for me and there was no reaction.
In return for your efforts, I have sent my own code to satisfy your curiosity, you can look at it and check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a sample of solution maybe i have no checked all your validation, but you have an idea how to do:

```
    private void TextBox27_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

        // Check if there is already a comma present in the TextBox's text
        bool commaExists = textBox.Text.Contains(",");
        int maxLength = 9;

        // check if key del or back is pressed
        if(e.Key == Key.Delete || e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Decimal || e.Key == Key.OemPeriod || e.Key == Key.OemComma)
        {
            if (!commaExists && textBox.Text.Length < maxLength)
            {
                // Replace dot with comma
                int caretIndex = textBox.CaretIndex;
                textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Insert(caretIndex, ",");

                // Move caret after the comma
                textBox.CaretIndex = caretIndex + 1;

                // Mark the event as handled
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Mark the event as handled to prevent the dot from being entered
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else if ((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9))
        {
            // Check if adding a new character would exceed the maximum length
            if (textBox.Text.Length >= maxLength )
            {
                // Mark the event as handled to prevent additional characters
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If the pressed key is not a number, a dot, or a comma, mark the event as handled
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @MuharremAdalmış: I rejected your edit suggestion since it completely replaces this answer. If you want, you may answer your own question as a separate answer.